# Body Not Displaying Full Width on Mobile Device

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a custom wordpress theme and I've been trying to debug this issue for days but can't figure it out. Would greatly appreciate your guys help!

On mobile devices - portrait view, the body isn't full width. On desktop browsers it works fine, even when you reduce the browser width to the same size as a mobile device.

Screenshot from my iphone -

**Mobile screenshot**

[image]

I already have this tag in the head -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

My site - [laxgoalierat.com](http://laxgoalierat.com)

Edit: As you see the page initially loads on the mobile device with full width however then it adjusts to what is seen in the screenshot.

I've tried playing around with the body CSS. Making body position:fixed makes it expand the full width however then I cannot scroll up and down :(

I'm out of other ideas. Let me know if providing any other details would help.

Thanks in advance, Damon

Comment: It appears to be an issue with just *part* of your HTML. The horrendous, kill-it kill-it mailing list banner does appear to expand correctly, but the body is not. Could you try posting at least the HTML and CSS that is applied to the root level of the page? The best thing would be is if you can give us a minimal reproducible example as a small page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your offending HTML seems to be coming from elements similar to this:

`<div class="yui-skin-sam avpcw_container">...</div>`

I don't know what these are or what they do...  But they are the reason for the effects you are seeing.

So a quick and dirty approach would be to apply css to hide either or both of these classes to patch over your problem. For example:

```
.yui-skin-sam {
    display: none;
}
```

Obviously you need to be sure that hiding these classes is appropriate.  I had a quick look to try to work out what they are used for; but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! Perfect guidance. I can take it from here!

Comment: Although not specifically my issue, using the `display: none;` tactic helped me track down my offending div. Thanks!